# Linking phone number to accounts with signin method of email and password on firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am following the instruction described [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/manage-mfa-users) to create accounts on firebase using email and password and then adding a phone number as 2FA for MFA. Now I want when the users login with their email and password on the frontend in react native to link their phoneNumber to their accounts. Reason for this is I want my users to login either with their phones or emails. Here is how I am doing this. I am basically trying to link accounts after OTP verification.

```js
const onVerifyOtp = async (otp: string) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const credential = auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, otp);
      const multiFactorAssertion =
        auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(credential);

      // Complete sign in
      const userCredential = await resolve.resolveSignIn(multiFactorAssertion);

      if (userCredential.user) {
        // link the phone number to the authenticated user
        await auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
      }

      const newuser = new UserInterface();
      newuser.id = userCredential.user?.uid || '';
      newuser.phoneNumber = userCredential.user?.phoneNumber || '';
      newuser.otpRequested = true;
      setLoading(false);
      setLogins(0);
      setUser(newuser);
      setUserData(newuser);
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(invalidOtp);
      setLoading(false);
      logger.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Yet for some reason this is not working. Keeps on throwing the error.

**Error: [auth/unsupported-first-factor] Enrolling a second factor or signing in with a multi-factor account requires sign-in with a supported first factor.**

At the point i am trying to link the accounts, the user is already signed in so I am not sure why this error. Can anyone help me figure this out?

**UPDATE**
Here is the code responsible for creating user in Firebase. As you can see we are correctly adding 2FA and setting email to verified

```js
const user = await firebase.auth().createUser({
        email,
        password,
        emailVerified: true,
        multiFactor: {
          enrolledFactors: [
            // Primary second factor
            {
              phoneNumber: phone,
              factorId: 'phone'
            }
          ]
        }
      });
```

[

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MFA` it's not possible to use `Phone Number` as a first login as the error states,

> Error: [auth/unknown] UNSUPPORTED_FIRST_FACTOR : A phone number cannot be set as a first factor on an SMS based MFA user.

> NativeFirebaseError: [auth/unknown] UNSUPPORTED_FIRST_FACTOR : A phone number cannot be set as a first factor on an SMS based MFA user.

So you have two options (without custom auth provider):

1. Use `MFA` (Multi-Factor Authentication) with email login.
2. Disable `MFA` and use `Email` or `Phone Number` as a way to login.

You can however handle this yourself with [custom-provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) which allows you (but also requires you) to take control of the auth flow yourself.

Comment: We have programmatically verified our users emails and added 2FA to their Firebase accounts as you can see in the latest updat